# Почему команда не выполняется до конца? Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Можно ли как-то продолжить выполнение кода после return? Функция привязана к нажатию на кнопку, можно ли как-то обойти return, чтобы выполнился остальной код?

```
global path
path = 'dataset'
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

def click_button2():

    imagePaths = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]     
    faceSamples=[]
    ids = []
    for imagePath in imagePaths:

        PIL_img = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L')
        img_numpy = np.array(PIL_img,'uint8')

        id = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[1])
        faces = detector.detectMultiScale(img_numpy)

        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            faceSamples.append(img_numpy[y:y+h,x:x+w])
            ids.append(id)         
    return faceSamples,ids
#код дальше не выполняется
    print ("\n [INFO] Загрузка лиц. Пожалуйста, ожидайте.")
    faces,ids = click_button2()
    recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ids))
    recognizer.write('trainer/trainer.yml') 
    print("\n [INFO] {0} лиц(а) добавлены.".format(len(np.unique(ids))))
```

Наверно исправил, разделив на 2 функции и добавив новую кнопку для второй функции, а потом узнал, что есть lambda и удалил вторую кнопку :)

```
def click_button2v():
    print ("\n [INFO] Загрузка лиц. Пожалуйста, ожидайте.")
    faces,ids = click_button2()
    recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ids))
    recognizer.write('trainer/trainer.yml') 
    print("\n [INFO] {0} лиц(а) добавлены.".format(len(np.unique(ids))))
```

Comment: Если разобрались, добавьте свое решение в ответы. В вопросе должен быть только вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

return всегда завершает выполнение функции. Можешь перенести остальной код перед return.

Comment: Если перенести код перед return, то получится бесконечный цикл.